# Why arrow function call gets red on my test coverage, but bind function not?2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am having this code in my App component

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
export default function App() {
  const [size, changeSize] = useState("You didn't press any button yet");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p id="para1" onClick={() => changeSize("big")}>
        Make the text big
      </p>
      <p onClick={() => changeSize("small")}>Make the text small</p>
      <div>
        <h3>Change the font size by pressing a button</h3>
      </div>
      <div id="result" className={`box ${size}`}>
        {size}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In my App.test.js file ii have

```
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import App from "./App";
import React from 'react';

describe("App", () => {
  it("renders correctly", () => {
    shallow(<App />);
  });
});

it("includes two paragraphs", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  expect(wrapper.find("p").length).toEqual(2);
});

it("should update state on click", () => {
  const changeSize = jest.fn();
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />); 
  const handleClick = jest.spyOn(React, "useState");
  handleClick.mockImplementation(size => [size, changeSize]);

  wrapper.find("#para1").simulate("click");
  expect(changeSize).toBeTruthy();
});
```

and if i run
`npm run test -- --coverage`

then i will get red line for
`<p onClick={() => changeSize("small")}>Make the text small</p>` line of code.

That is because in my test, i am not testing for some id like in the first case `para1`.

But i noticed that if my function all in my component is changed from arrow function into function binding

```
 <p onClick={changeSize.bind(null, "small")}>Make the text small</p>
```

then with the same app.test.js applied test i don't get the red line coverage in my test

WHY THE HECK IS THAT ?

btw the code is getted by

https://blog.logrocket.com/testing-state-changes-in-react-functional-components/

Comment: Your test doesn't make a lot of sense, of course `changeSize` will be truthy, you defined it in the test! Why not just include a test that exercises the second p-tag's `onClick` callback so you get the code coverage you're looking for? You get the code coverage in the second implementation because `changeSize.bind(null, "small")` had to be evaluated to return a callback for the click event.

Comment: @Draw thanks for your reseponse. I got the code and tests from the provided link.I am new to testing and react and i maked few changes in the code and then i noticed about the red coverage with the arrow function... Can you please provide an answer - example for the comment you wrote ?

Comment: Why i don't get then red coverage for the first case - first paragraph - there is also arrow function - but with the test is is covereted... i dont understand that

Comment: Because your tests don't interact with the second `<p>`, so you don't get the code coverage for that click handler.

Comment: I know that,my question was why it is covered when i use bind function, why it is not when i use ARROW FUNCTION!

Comment: not depending on the p interaction, with the same test here...........